# WinForms form freezes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

On a form (F1) i have a button, from which if i create another form (lets call it F2) and show it there's no problem

but i'd like to do something like this

Some thread in my app is running a connection and listens for messages from a server. when a message arrives, my main form is registered to get an event that runs a function. From that function i'm trying to create and show the F2 type form (empty, nothing modified in it): it shows it but then it freezes my application.

more exactly:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ConnectionManagerThread.getResponseListener().MessageReceived += Form1_OnMessageReceived;
    }

    private void Form1_OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e) {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried catching those lines you think causes the freeze?

Comment: the freeze happens after f2.Show(). there is no error, no exceptions going on. my guess is that the problem might be because the form is practically being started from another thread

Comment: Is form2 also frozen or just form1?

Comment: @andrew In which case I would guess that form2 wasn't created from the UI thread and so doesn't have an associated message pump.  @Ram's answer will be probably be the solution (once you guys have debugged it :) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the reason is you are performing cross thread operations. You need to put the creation of the form on the UI thread before creating form2. I think following will help you

```
  public delegate void ShowForm(object sender, MessageEventArgs e);
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
     public Form1()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
        ConnectionManagerThread.getResponseListener().MessageReceived += Form1_OnMessageReceived;
     }

     private void Form1_OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
     {
         if (this.InvokeRequired)
         {
            this.BeginInvoke(new ShowForm((Form1_OnMessageReceived), new object[] { sender, e }));
         }
         else
         {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
         }
      }
  }
```

Comment: i think there's a problem with the "this.BeginInvoke(new ShowForm(new object[] { sender, e }));" line. it says "error CS0149: Method name expected"

Comment: @andrew - check now, I forgot to put target name :).

Answer (score 2):

using Ram's code i finally got to this and it works

thanx!

```
public delegate void ShowForm(object sender, MessageEventArgs e);

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ConnectionManagerThread.getResponseListener().MessageReceived += Form1_OnMessageReceived;
    }

     private void Form1_OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
     {
         ShowForm2(sender, e);
     }

    private void ShowForm2(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            ShowForm f = new ShowForm(ShowForm2);
            this.Invoke(f, new object[] { sender, e });
        }
        else
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
        }
    }
}
```