# Why does windows form freeze when it loads in C#?

Tags: c#, sql

I am new to C# and I am using `windows forms`.
I am building an application and I am facing a strange serious problem when `Form` loads.

I have 2 `forms`:

`Form1` has a  `button_Edit` and `DataGridView`

`Form2` has a `DataGridView1` and `DataGridView2`

As it is shown in the code and the screen shot, in `Form1` when I select a row in `DataGridView` then click on `Button_Edit` the  `Order number` and `DateTime`  values in `DataGridView` on `Form1` are passed to `Form2` and then `Form2` opens up.
Now in `Form2` `Load event` there is a `SQL` query which takes `Order number` and `DateTime` to bring the relevant order details and then fill `DataGridView1` and `DataGridView2` in `Form2`.

[image: screenShot]

- In Form1:

  ```
  Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
  private void button_Edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
   {

       frm2._ Order_Number= Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
       frm2._ Date_Time= Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value);

       frm2.ShowDialog();

   }
  ```
- In Form2:

  ```
    SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand();
    DataTable DataTable = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter Sql_Data_Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

  int Order_Number;
  DateTime Date_Time;
  int i;
  double Sum;
  int RowIndex;

   public int _ Order_Number
    {

        set { Order_Number = value; }
    }


    public DateTime _ Date_Time
    {

        set { Date_Time = value; }
    }

   private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {


              DataTable.Rows.Clear();
              DataTable.Columns.Clear();

              MyConnection.Open();

              MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customer_Order_Details WHERE Order_Number = @OrderNumber and Date_Time = @DateTime ";
              MyCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
              MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@OrderNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Order_Number;
              MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@DateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date_Time;

              Sql_Data_Adapter.SelectCommand = MyCommand;
              Sql_Data_Adapter.Fill(DataTable);
              MyCommand.Parameters.Clear();
              MyConnection.Close();

              dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
              dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = 0;

              Sum = 0;

              //////////////FILL THE ORDER INTO DATAGRIDVIEW1///////////
               RowIndex = DataTable.Rows.Count - 1;
              for (i = 0; i <= RowIndex; i++)
              {

                  dataGridView1.Rows.Add(DataTable.Rows[i][2], DataTable.Rows[i][3], DataTable.Rows[i][4]);

                   // Calculate the total:
                  Sum = Convert.ToDouble(DataTable.Rows[i][4]) + Sum;                       

              }

              dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = sum;


  }
  ```
- The issue:

This code works fine and as I wanted and `DataGridView1` & `DataGridView2` in `Form2` are filled with the right details and it works fine when `Form2` loads.
However, sometimes `Form2` freezes after filling both `DataGridView1` & `DataGridView2` when `Form2` loads and I can not do anything until I kill the Application using Task manager.
This issue happens sometimes and it is unpredictable. I really don’t know what is wrong.

I had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566006/form-does-not-do-anything-freezes-while-an-operation-is-busy) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863808/winforms-form-freezes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816153/form-freezes-during-while-loop) but non of those questions related to my issue. Note that I already use try catch and it does not throw anything because the form freezes. This freeze behavior occurs in the release mode I mean after I build EXE file then I install it in a PC and here the issue happens.

Has anyone got any idea why this bad unpredictable behavior occurs? 
Is there anything that I should change in my code? 
I will be very happy to listen to any new ideas/solutions no matter how small it is, it will be very beneficial.
Thank you

Comment: It means your application got halted on some point from your code. surround your code with try catch and print the stack trace

Comment: you should populate DataGridView via asynchronous methods which fixes the problem?

Comment: @ Roljhon . I already use try catch and it does not throw anything because the form freezes.

Comment: do you know exactly where it gets stuck? also consider using `using` for connections. it should be disposed when it is not used anymore

Comment: @Serena you mean even visual studio is freezing? have you tried running your application alone without starting it from visual studio?

Comment: why are you creating connection on the top? did you try to create both connection and command and adapter as well on `Form_Load`

Comment: @ a-man. I do not really know. all I know is it freezes just after it fills both DGV in Form2

Comment: @Roljhon. No. this freeze behavior occurs in the release mode. I mean after I build EXE file then install it in a PC and here the issue happens.

Comment: @a-man . Good point to place the connections in Load and see what happens. I will try it.

Answer (score 2):

Do SQL work on another thread. Check out Asynchronous call.

[BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `Async` versions of `Open` (connecting to RDBMS) and `ExecuteReader` (query executing):

```
con.Open()        -> await con.OpenAsync()
q.ExecuteReader() -> await q.ExecuteReaderAsync()
```

this easy substitution makes UI *responsible* (it doesn't *freeze*) while connecting to RDBMS and executing the query.

```
// do not forget to mark Form2_Load method as async 
private async void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // Do not share the connection - create it and dispose for each call 
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(...)) {
    await con.OpenAsync();

    string sql = 
      @"SELECT * 
          FROM Customer_Order_Details 
         WHERE Order_Number = @OrderNumber 
           AND Date_Time = @DateTime";

    // do not share command/query as well 
    using (SqlCommand q = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
      q.Parameters.Add("@OrderNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Order_Number;
      q.Parameters.Add("@DateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Date_Time;

      dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
      dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = 0;

      Sum = 0;

      // We actually don't want any sql adapter: 
      // all we have to do is to fetach data from cursor and append it to grids
      using (var reader = await q.ExecuteReaderAsync()) {
        while (reader.Read()) {
          dataGridView1.Rows.Add(reader[2], reader[3], reader[4]);
          Sum += Convert.ToDouble(reader[4]);  
        }
      } 
    }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as said the code snippet you gave us isn't well written. You should use more Try/Catch Statements to prevent crashs and freezes on your programm. This will help you to find bugs even while running the Programm in release. Furthermore you have many options to solve your problem.

1:
Try to start Form2 in a second thread, then only your form2 will freeze until your sql finishes

2:
As mentioned before try to use asyncronous calls to avoid freeze time of handling the sql

3:
There is no direct need of a SQL Database/Connection. You could also use a Collection and create objects defined of your Products (like cola) and them bind them through the database. (If you are interested in i could show you a example)

The best way for you would be:

Add some Try/Catch Statements and get familiar with it, get familiar with Systems.Thread and try to start your form2 in a new thread if this doenst work go to step 2 and add asynchronus calls

In the end i would like to tell you, that namen your Forms "Form1" and "Form2" isn't nice could maybe you like to change it.

Comment: thank you for your advice. can I do the sql query in separate thread?